# SVG Animatemotion Path not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, path

Okay so I have this big svg file which is a map and have now created a little dot that moves along on the map. It works perfectly fine in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. I have tried adding a begin="1s" thinking that maybe Firefox just didn't know when to start but that didn't work.  Any idea why? Does Firefox have a problem with animatemotion path?

```
<circle cx="" cy="" r="5" fill="#1f6527"> <animateMotion path="M110,130, C150 150,150 40, 270 200  C280 210, 290 210, 510 190 C520 210, 600 150, 705 140 C720 160, 720 160, 710 250 C 710 280, 720 280, 710 320 C710 310, 710 310, 720 470 L765 500" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> </circle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is invalid. According to the [path grammar as written in the SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) commas are only allowed between numbers so the second comma here `M110,130, C150` makes the path invalid from that point.

Firefox follows the SVG specification as written whereas Chrome is somewhat laxer.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="5" fill="#1f6527"> <animateMotion path="M110,130 C150 150,150 40, 270 200  C280 210, 290 210, 510 190 C520 210, 600 150, 705 140 C720 160, 720 160, 710 250 C 710 280, 720 280, 710 320 C710 310, 710 310, 720 470 L765 500" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> </circle></svg>
```